# Is “he should be seventeen” correct?

Tags: tenses, modal-verbs, should, aspect

Is the following sentence correct to describe a young man?

> He should be seventeen.

My colleague was absolutely sure it was correct. I disagreed, so we had a bit of an argument. I would agree on either

> He should be seventeen before he. . . .

or

> He should be seventeen by now.

If the original sentence (“He should be seventeen.”) is actually correct,  what makes it so?

Comment: It certainly seems *grammatically* correct.

Comment: Your question might be a better fit for [the English Language Learners Stack Exchange site](http://ell.stackexchange.com) than here.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context. If someone asked you how old your third cousin is (whom, for example, you rarely see), you could respond with 'He should be seventeen'. Or, if a young lady asked you the appropriate age for a young man to date, you could respond the same. The way you're phrasing it, the statement sounds like a response to a question. You could desciribe someone this way, but it really is a vague description.

Comment: Yes - modals are famously used to convey different meanings. In the first answer the OP sanctions, 'he should be ...' means 'there is a requirement that he be ...'. In the second answer OP sanctions, it means 'by my reckoning, he is very close to being ...'. The initial, debated sentence is a shortened form (of either sense), and, as MDMoore313 implies, requires context (when it becomes quite acceptable).

Comment: It depends on whether you intend the "deontic" use of _should_, which refers to weak obligation (_You should get that bandage changed_), or the "epistemic" use of _should_, which refers to calculated probability (_You should be standing in front of a brass door right now_). [All modals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf) are ambiguous that way.